# Как восстановить поврежденный pdf на c#

Tags: c#, pdf

Интересует возможность восстановить поврежденный файл pdf, сделав консольное приложение на c#. Сайтов которые предлагают это сделать онлайн очень много, а вот как это реализовать на C# так негде и не нашёл. Заранее спасибо, за любую помощь в решении данного вопроса.

P.S могу сбросить для примера поврежденный файл и восстановлений.

Comment: Для начала напишите программу, которая способна прочитать нормальный PDF, разобрать его на логические части, затем собрать обратно и записать в новый файл, который в теории должен быть идентичен исходному. Затем реализуйте обработку всякого рода ошибок при разборке файла. У вас в результате и получится примерно то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Еще подсказка: Поищите NuGet пакеты для работы с PDF. Большинство из них имеет исходники на Github.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.